# EF changing data type from string to int, how to drop and add column during migrations

Tags: entity-framework

I am changing a column from string to int on one table. The migration got built fine with `ef migrations add` but when trying to run `update` I was got an error that

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'MyField' to data
>   type int.

I don't need the data so I figured I could modify the up/down to just drop and re-add the columns instead of an alter. This is the old up/down

```
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
            name: "MyField",
            table: "MyTable",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(string));
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
            name: "MyField",
            table: "MyTable",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(int));
    }
```

I changed that the below

```
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn("MyField", "MyTable");
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
            name: "MyField",
            table: "MyTable",
            nullable: false);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn("MyField", "MyTable");
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "MyField",
            table: "MyTable",
            nullable: false);
    }
```

Now when running `ef database update` I am getting a new error that would make sense...except I cannot find an ALTER TABLE anywhere!

> ALTER TABLE only allows columns to be added that can contain nulls, or
>   have a DEFAULT definition specified, or the column being added is an
>   identity or timestamp column, or alternatively if none of the previous
>   conditions are satisfied the table must be empty to allow addition of
>   this column. Column 'PlanType' cannot be added to non-empty table
>   'Subscriptions' because it does not satisfy these conditions.

What could I be missing that's not allowing me to do this?

** Resolved

Per @strickt01 answer I just had to allow nullable from Down and supply a default value in Up

```
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn("MyField", "MyTable");
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
            name: "MyField",
            table: "MyTable",
            defaultValue: 1,
            nullable: false);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn("MyField", "MyTable");
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "MyField",
            table: "MyTable");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dropping the column and then re-creating it does not clear out the data in the table. Your `Subscriptions` table will still have rows. Thus when you try to add the column which you declare as non-nullable with no default value you get the error (SQL cannot populate the current rows with non-null values without a default). The `ALTER TABLE` statement is referenced because that is the SQL for adding a column:

```
ALTER TABLE Subscription ADD PlanType int not null
```

See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

You will either need to declare a default or create it as non-nullable, populate it as part of the migration and then change it to non-nullable.

Comment: sweet thanks, removed `nullable: false` from Down and added `defaultValue: 1` to Up and everything is gravy